# Elasticsearch on Azure virtual machine

Tags: windows, azure, elasticsearch, azure-virtual-machine

I have installed elasticsearch on Azure virtual machine.
I have installed the elasticsearch service which which automatically starts on system start up.

Everything works fine on VM. I can access the 9200 port of elasticsearch instance.

The problem is I can not access it with the help of dns name of the virtual machine i.e. xyz.cloudapp.net:9200

I have created endpoints for 9200 and 9300 port.

[image]

I want the Elasticsearch on just one VM for now.
Am I missing any steps?

Comment: Any chance you have a firewall configured on the machine that block the access ?
Can you post your endpoint definition, please ?

Comment: I have edited the question with the end points image

Comment: I tried the same thing with mongoDB and it works fine. FYI.

Comment: When you say "I can access the 9200 port of elasticsearch instance", do you mean you can access it from the VM it is running on? Or you can access it from a remote machine? Is the elasticsearch service binding to localhost/127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 (or some other network interface)? Is the virtual machine Classic or Resource Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question is here.
I needed to add the following to my Elasticsearch config file

```
network.host: [_local_, _site_]
```

This works like a charm.

This has been added in ElasticSearch since 2.x.x version.

Thanks

Comment: For anyone having trouble with `_site_`, try adding the private IP of the VM. 

(Note: please please do not do this for any ElasticSearch instance that hosts important data or anything of value, because doing so is supremely insecure)